# Where is the Winter 15 Release Developer Preview Video?

Tags: apex, visualforce, release, video

I got used to a regular youtube video salesforce has provided for earlier releases like this

https://developer.salesforce.com/en/events/webinars/summer_2014_release

Does anyone know if there is or will be a version for winter 15? I was googleing for it but unfortunately not successful yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, on [release page](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter15) it is sayed that  'Winter 15 Release Webinar
Coming soon'.